# Retrieve all term IDs of post

Tags: taxonomy, query, terms

I have an array of term IDs that I'd like to filter my query with, but most wordpress functions seem to need the 'taxonomy' field entered too. Is there a reason for this?

Passing the taxonomy ID seems to be unnecessary, if all term IDs are unique anyway, unless I'm missing something.

As it seems as though I can't query this with Wordpress direct, I'd be looking for something like:

```
$terms_array = get_term_ids( get_the_ID() );
```

Any ideas of the best way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code and see if it works for you, I just cooked it up real quick and haven't tested it, so it may be way off base, but the concept is there.

```
$tax_args = array(
    'public' => true
);
$taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $tax_args, 'names', 'or' );

$term_args = array(
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$terms = get_terms( $taxonomies, $term_args );
```

Docs: [`get_taxonomies()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomies), [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)

Comment: Looks good! I'll check this in the morning & let you know.